# Trying to understand why you would use this type of database setup

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I recently came across a database being set up in this manner.

```
<?php
ini_set( "display_errors", true );
date_default_timezone_set( "Australia/Sydney" );  // http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
define( "DB_DSN", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms" );
define( "DB_USERNAME", "root" );
define( "DB_PASSWORD", "" );
define( "CLASS_PATH", "classes" );
define( "TEMPLATE_PATH", "templates" );
define( "HOMEPAGE_NUM_ARTICLES", 5 );
define( "ADMIN_USERNAME", "admin" );
define( "ADMIN_PASSWORD", "mypass" );
require( CLASS_PATH . "/Article.php" );

function handleException( $exception ) {
  echo "Sorry, a problem occurred. Please try later.";
  error_log( $exception->getMessage() );
}

set_exception_handler( 'handleException' );
?>
```

I understand how its working but I've never seen a connection being set up like this, is there a reason why you would want to set up your database in this manner?

Comment: What manner? Using constants?

Comment: This is for connecting to database with PDO statements.

Comment: `Why would you use this type of database setup?` Because in this way you can create 1 config.php to store all settings.

Comment: @pregmatch oh ok that makes sense. I'm very new to php so I'm still used to seeing connections done as $con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123"); etc.. etc.. Thanks!

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario yes, is it common to use constants like this to connect to a database? Excuse my lack of knowledge, I'm new to php.

Comment: It's common to use constants to store constant information, such as database credentials. It's foolish to spread your password all around the code base.

Comment: @Bondye Perfect! I see what you mean. Is it common to use constants like this to connect to a database? thanks for your response.

Comment: @catmat Yes it is, I create configs like this. Also i've seen wordpress, joomla, drupal, PHPMailer etc doing this. Its is safe and very easy to use these setting EVERYWHERE in your application.

Comment: You guys have been a lot of help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very common scenario. I created a MySQL class that I use in my PHP projects, and can call it from anywhere to connect to the database. You can grab it here:

http://pastebin.com/2FrPHVLR

For any pages that need to connect to my database, I load a global config file that requires that class, and add my credentials, like

```
$db_hostspec = 'localhost';
$db_database = 'mydb';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = 'MySekretPassw0rd';
$db_port = '3306';
```

Then, I can connect to the database with

```
$db = new MySQL($db_hostspec, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
```

And I can make calls to the database with:

```
$products = $db->execute("SELECT * FROM Products");
```

Comment: This was spot on what I was looking for! Cant +1 yet but you have my gratitude, Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Great, it's saved me a ton of time and headaches--hope it does for you too. Check out the class for more options other than `execute`