# How can I access sql login info outside of web root

Tags: php, mysql, web, passwords, root

I'm a newbie.

I have a php script located here `/var/www/check_login.php` that includes sql login information in plain text.  This file is accessed to verify correct user credentials by my login page `/var/www/login.php` via `<form name="" method="post" action="check_login.php">`

I'd like to store `check_login.php` outside of web root directory so it cannot be accessed remotely.

How would I tell `login.php` to access `check_login.php` outside of the web root directory?

I'm guessing its not as simple as `action="/var/<new folder outside of root>/check_login.php`

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move file with credentials to one level up directory and in file check_login.php

```
include('../credentials.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Create a different folder for your site in /var/www. I like to do this setup:

```
/var
---/www
-------/mysite
----------/html
----------/config
----------/lib
```

etc. In apache, I tell it my document home is

`/var/www/mysite/html`

and then I store any config files (like MySQL credentials or classes) in `/var/www/mysite/config`. Then, I can include these files with something like:

`require_once("/var/www/mysite/config/mydbcreds.php")`

In your example, `login.php` would need to call your check function in this file, and would be able to if you require it to be included. [Check out my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608878/trying-to-understand-why-you-would-use-this-type-of-database-setup/13609836#13609836) on how to use a MySQL connection class that may save you some time and headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new page for your database connection information and move that to `/var/`

You can then use your HTML `action="check_login.php"`

and on your check_login.php script, use the solution which Gustek suggested:

`include('../credentials.php');`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `include('path of folders/ your_ logging_data .php`);

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a shared hosting plan, I would simply create a new folder outside my website root and have all my non-public files in there. Then in the **php.ini** file for your website, I would edit the include path to include this new folder. In your .php file, simple put `require("the-non-public-file.php");` at the top, i.e, without the absolute path.